# Android: Vector Icons on pre Lollipop devices

Tags: android

:)
I created a drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/Black"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0"
        android:strokeColor="@color/White"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5" />
</vector>
```

But this works only for APIs >= 21 devices. I would like to use something like this on pre lollipop devices. Here is the result of the drawable:

[Drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH7yG.png)

Just a circular image but with fixed width and height..

Comment: if you just need a circle there is no need for vector.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported in AppCompat v23.2.0.

See this [Vector Drawables in AppCompat](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.8pfdl2vqv)

Answer (score 0):

Now we have support library 23.2 and it allow to use VectorDrawableCompat back to API 7 and AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat on all API 11 and higher devices. Android studio not ready for this yet so ignore warnings.

There is one serious limitation - you can't use vector drawables and animated vector drawables directly as `android:background` and `android:src` on older androids. But this can be solved by wrapping drawable into `<layer-list></layer-list>` or `<selector></selector>` or using `app:srcCompat` attribute in `AppCompatImageView` widget.

[Some kind of pre-tutorial from Android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Comment: any sample working <layer-list></layer-list> or <selector></selector> with svg for pre lolipop  devices